# Regarding next LTS upgrade - 20.x

Tags: upgrade, updates, 19.10

I am on 19.10 release which is not LTS, 20.x will be released in April, that time will I able to upgrade directy from 19.10 or I do downgrade to latest 18.x release for next LTS upgrade ?

Comment: Ubuntu has two upgrade paths, all releases (ie 18.04 -> 18.10 -> 19.04 -> 19.10 -> 20.04) OR LTS to *next* LTS (18.04 to 20.04 when 20.04.1 is released)...  This is what user535733 has said in different wording; the LTS option is delayed until .1 is released to ensure stability (LTS users prefer stability..)   Only the first release of an even year is LTS, ie. 20.04 LTS,  20.10 will be a standard release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to release-upgrade directly from 19.10 to 20.04.

LTS releases are ordinary 6-month releases of Ubuntu...that simply happen to have longer support periods for those users who want that particular pattern.

Users of interim releases will upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04 in April 2020, and then from 20.04 to 20.10 in October 2020. Users of LTS releases will use 16.04 or 18.04 or 20.04 until their support period ends, and then upgrade to the next LTS release.